# QTableView / QStandardItemModel update without losing selection / sort order

Tags: qt, qt4, qtableview

Currently I want to update row items in a `QStandardItemModel` **without** losing the sort order and row selection in the respective `QTableView`.

I have tested two approaches:

1. Clearing the model by `clear()` and re-adding the rows "destroys" everything including headers.
2. [Removing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768266/qstandarditemmodelremoverows-does-not-work-in-my-use-case) and re-adding all rows keeps the headers, but still "destroys" selection and sort order.

I could try to manually to a) remove all rows no longer required and then b) update the items of the changed rows. But is there no easier way?

Comment: have you tried using QProxyModel? The docs now say that it is outdated, but may serve your purpose

Comment: I do not see how this would help me. I could update all data on the proxy first, but then? What's the basic idea?

Comment: Proxy should handle selections and sort order and data model just provide the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know, how you sorted your data before the update, but please take a look at the QTableView's [sortByColumn()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#sortByColumn) function.

As for the selection, if it still keeps disappearing, you can manually put back your selection, where it should be by:

```
// You access the selected index when the editing starts
QModelIndex index = table->selectionModel()->currentIndex();

//Later when you finished editing, you can select it again
table->selectionModel()->select(index, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

More about this:

- [QItemSelectionModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qitemselectionmodel.html)
- [QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can either remove the rows no longer required and add the new ones or manually remember the sort order and which items were selected before clearing. I.e. assign a unique ID (one can use setData() with a custom role for that), retrieve that before clearing from the selected items, and reapply the selection after recreating the items.